# Android: hotspot with 2 dnsmasq runs at the same time

Tags: android, shell, command-line

When I activate hotspot in android phone, the default DNSMASQ of the system runs on along.
 

USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
nobody    2689  149   1008   488   c06fadd8 400d80d8 S /system/bin/dnsmasq
But I want to have my own configuration so before activate the hotspot, I create the dnsmasq configuration myself. Then when I activate it, there seem to be 2 dnsmasq services run at the same time.

I kill the system one using (kill -9 pid) but it doesn't seem to work, it still there ? 

nobody    2780  1     1012   312   c0856674 400a8d44 S dnsmasq
root      2797  149   0      0     c061c654 00000000 Z dnsmasq

Any suggestion how to kill it ?

Answer (score 0):

The Z indicates it's a zombie process, so it has been terminated, it just hasn't been tidied up yet.